# Determining the pair of natural numbers that closest approximate a square while maintaining a specific area

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

So, I'm trying to draw an HTML table as close to being a square as possible from a value passed in. For example, if the number passed in is 16, then the output would be 4x4. Since not all numbers have a whole square root, the output for a number like 12 would be 4x3 (not 1x12 or 2x6). The output for a prime number like 7 would be 7x1. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hi nikpmr, welcome to StackOverflow.  Please clarify your question - are you wanting to find the set of integers that most closely approximates a square, or do you want to create an HTML table from a set of elements describing it's dimensions?

Comment: Do you need help with the HTML/Javascript side of the problem, or just the math?

Comment: Well I can figure out the HTML part, just the math is messing me up.

Comment: That's not what the title of your question states :).  To get the best response, your title should meaningfully reflect what you are asking.  Based on the title, most people would assume you are having problems creating HTML tables.

Comment: Seems very doable via `style='width:4em;height:3em'`, perhaps it would be good to clarify what exactly you need assistance with accomplishing?  The math for determining the sizes to use, I assume? Whoops, duplicating comments that others already made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general procedure you can follow:

Take the floor of the square root of the number and see if your number is divisible by that without a remainder.  Keep subtracting 1 and repeating the process until you get a number that is divisible without a remainder.  Then take the result of your starting number divided by that number as your second dimension.

**UPDATE:**

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/kSZXX/) an example JavaScript solution based on the above solution.